# Elaborando un Keyboard en Android Studio - ¿Como le agrego los superindices a las teclas?

Tags: android-studio

Estoy elaborando un **teclado** (*keyboard*) en **Android Studio**, pero me he quedado estancado sobre **como poder colocar los superíndices a las teclas** (*ver círculos rojos en la imagen*), en el teclado de la imagen de ejemplo, sobre la Q colocan un 1, sobre la W un 2, además sobre la ',' colocan el icono del micrófono y sobre el punto '.' colocan tres caracteres ',!?' (*ver imagen al final*) Como hago para agregarle esos superíndices ?

**Se agregan en el código XML o se agregan en Tiempo de Ejecución en Java?**

> El codigo XML que tengo es el siguiente.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="60dp"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:verticalGap="0px">

    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="49"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="1" />
        <Key
            android:codes="50"
            android:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key
            android:codes="51"
            android:keyLabel="3" />
        <Key
            android:codes="52"
            android:keyLabel="4" />
        <Key
            android:codes="53"
            android:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key
            android:codes="54"
            android:keyLabel="6" />
        <Key
            android:codes="55"
            android:keyLabel="7" />
        <Key
            android:codes="56"
            android:keyLabel="8" />
        <Key
            android:codes="57"
            android:keyLabel="9" />
        <Key
            android:codes="48"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="0" />
    </Row>
    <!--- Fila: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 -->

    <Row>
        <Key android:keyLabel="q" android:codes="113" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="w" android:codes="119"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="e" android:codes="101"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="r" android:codes="114"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="t" android:codes="116"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="y" android:codes="121"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="u" android:codes="117"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="i" android:codes="105"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="o" android:codes="111"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="p" android:codes="112" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"  />

    </Row> <!--- Fila q w e r t y u i o p  -->

    <Row>
        <Key android:keyLabel="a" android:codes="97" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="s" android:codes="115"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="d" android:codes="100"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="f" android:codes="102"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="g" android:codes="103"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="h" android:codes="104"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="j" android:codes="106"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="k" android:codes="107"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="l" android:codes="108"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="ñ" android:codes="164"  />
        <Key android:keyLabel="\# \@" android:codes="35,64" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"  />
    </Row> <!--- Fila a s d f g h j k l ñ #@-->

    <Row>
        <Key android:keyLabel="CAPS" android:codes="-1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="" android:codes="-1" android:iconPreview="@mipmap/ic_keyboard_capslock_black_24dp" android:keyIcon="@mipmap/ic_keyboard_capslock_black_24dp" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="z" android:codes="122"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="x" android:codes="120"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="c" android:codes="99"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="v" android:codes="118"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="b" android:codes="98"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="n" android:codes="110"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="m" android:codes="109"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="," android:codes="46"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="." android:codes="108"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="\? ! :" android:codes="63,33,58" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row> <!--- Fila z x c v b n m -->

    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:keyLabel="," android:codes="44" android:keyWidth="10%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="/" android:codes="47" android:keyWidth="10%p"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:codes="32" android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="DEL" android:codes="-5" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="DONE" android:codes="-4" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>


</Keyboard>
```

> Y la clase en java:

```
package gmsoftware.tecladocrypgo;

import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;

import java.security.Key;

public class CrypgoKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;
    private boolean isCaps = false;

    /**
     * Create and return the view hierarchy used for the input area (such as
     * a soft keyboard).  This will be called once, when the input area is
     * first displayed.  You can return null to have no input area; the default
     * implementation returns null.
     * <p>
     * <p>To control when the input view is displayed, implement
     * {@link #onEvaluateInputViewShown()}.
     * To change the input view after the first one is created by this
     * function, use {@link #setInputView(View)}.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard (this,R.xml.qwerty);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user presses a key. This is sent before the {@link #onKey} is called.
     * For keys that repeat, this is only called once.
     *
     * @param primaryCode the unicode of the key being pressed. If the touch is not on a valid
     *                    key, the value will be zero.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {

    }

    /**
     * Called when the user releases a key. This is sent after the {@link #onKey} is called.
     * For keys that repeat, this is only called once.
     *
     * @param primaryCode the code of the key that was released
     */
    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {

    }

    /**
     * Send a key press to the listener.
     *
     * @param primaryCode this is the key that was pressed
     * @param keyCodes    the codes for all the possible alternative keys
     *                    with the primary code being the first. If the primary key code is
     *                    a single character such as an alphabet or number or symbol, the alternatives
     *                    will include other characters that may be on the same key or adjacent keys.
     *                    These codes are useful to correct for accidental presses of a key adjacent to
     */
    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {

        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        playClick(primaryCode);
        switch (primaryCode){
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                ic.deleteSurroundingText(1,0);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                isCaps = !isCaps;
                keyboard.setShifted(isCaps);
                kv.invalidateAllKeys();
                break;
            case  Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
                break;
            default:
                char code = (char) primaryCode;
                if (Character.isLetter(code) && isCaps)
                    code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
        }
    }

    private void playClick(int primaryCode) {
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch (primaryCode)
        {
            case 32:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            case 10:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
                break;
            default:
                am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends a sequence of characters to the listener.
     *
     * @param text the sequence of characters to be displayed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {

    }

    /**
     * Called when the user quickly moves the finger from right to left.
     */
    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {

    }

    /**
     * Called when the user quickly moves the finger from left to right.
     */
    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {

    }

    /**
     * Called when the user quickly moves the finger from up to down.
     */
    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {

    }

    /**
     * Called when the user quickly moves the finger from down to up.
     */
    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {

    }
}
```

**Como pregunta adicional, si pudieran decirme también como agregar ese layout en el marco rectángulo rojo sería de gran ayuda.**

Muchas gracias a todos !

[image: Teclado ejemplo Swiftkey]